# Python Memory Error using Numpy only with Ubuntu?

Tags: python, numpy, out-of-memory, ubuntu-18.04

I have a strange memory error when using Numpy on an Ubuntu server. The server has 64GB of RAM and 250GB additional swap space and memlock is unlimited.

However, if I type

```
import numpy as np

x = 1000000
np.zeros((x,x))
```

I get a memory error. If I do the same on my 16GB Ram Macbook it works fine.

How can this happen? I want to use the server for numerical experiments and it just doesn't work. The experiments run fine on my Macbook, and the Python process uses only 2GB of RAM. Is there a way to prevent the Memory Error on the server?

Comment: Given you fill the array with values, it will produce an error on both machines, since here you will need at least 1'000GB of memory to store the values if these are bytes, let alone if these are doubles (then that will result in 8'000GB).

Comment: So the only reason why this might work here, is because it used a *sparse* matrix. But from the moment you start "filling" the matrix with values, that will result in trouble.

Comment: So Mac OS seems to do a different kind of memory allocation? the resulting matrix will indeed be sparse, and it would be better to use sparse matrices from scipy, but the different behavior on the two machines is strange.

Comment: *"If I do the same on my 16GB Ram Macbook it works fine."*  It surely does not work as fine as you think.  Try, for example, `z = np.zeros(1000000, 1000000); z[...] = 1`.  That is, actually write data to all the elements of `z`.

Comment: Also, numpy does not create a sparse matrix on Mac OS.  Numpy does not have sparse matrices.  The difference is in how Mac OS handles memory allocation.